# mobilefirst ejb support when implementing adapter logic

Tags: ejb, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Is there, from an architectural point of view, a design pattern to migrate an existing web api component (realizing BL usign EJB integration with a backend component) into mobile first adapters (I think the java native type) in order to serve mobilefirst mobile apps?

Comment: Can you elaborate by providing some code you're trying to use?

Comment: Hi Idan thanks for the answer.
No code now: we're in exploring phase. Just to know the feasibility of this kind of porting.
I know we have js or java or hybrid (js calling java) implementation pattern: just to know if java or hybrid are able to support EJB web services integration (where these services are provided by an external component).

Answer (score 1):

EJB is not supported by MobileFirst Java adapters (and adapters in general)
However, if you consider to upgrade to MobileFirst 8.0, there is a simple way to use the Spring framework in Java adapters (see: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/24/MobileFirst-spring-integration-in-java-adapters/)

In many cases, EJB application can be migrated to spring, depends on which EJB features are used in it.

Comment: By the way, I found this tool: http://docs.spring.io/spring-migration-analyzer/docs/latest/user-guide/htmlsingle/ that should help in analyzing the effort of migration of EJB apps to spring. I must say I never tried it and I don't know if it fits the way we use spring in adapters, however I think it is worth looking at